# Javascript setInterval with ajax call making site slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have implemented the `setInterval()` function in javascript which makes AJAX call in every 2 minutes. The ajax call returns data which I append in html. I don't know why but it makes the website very slow, gradually. The website is developed in node js. I googled for the issue and got to know about the `clearInterval()` function. But I am unable to use it properly. Can someone give me a generic example of clearing the interval properly? Or is this some other issue related to node js?

Code Below:

```
setInterval(function() {    
appendData(skipCount);}, 120000);

function appendData(_popularSkipCount) {
    var cookieValue = $.cookie('type');         
    var _data = {
        "limit": defaultLimit - 1,
        "skipCount": _popularSkipCount
    }               
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/popular/" + cookieValue,
        data: _data,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {  
            $("#data-box").empty();
            if($(data).size() > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < $(data).size() ; i++) {
                    var html = "<div class='large-12 columns popular'><img class='image' src='" + $(data)[i].url + "' class='popular-img'><a href='/abc/" + $(data)[i].slug + "'><h4>" + name + "</h4></a><h5>" + city + "</h5></div>";
                    $(html).hide().appendTo("#data-box").fadeIn(1000);
                }
            } else {
                appendData("0");
            }               
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown) {                             
            $("#data-box").empty();
            console.log(errorthrown);
        }
    });     
};
```

Comment: my guess is you are using `synchronous` ajax calls too frequent.  Thereby causing the website slow

Comment: Provide relevant code in question itself

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @Praveen Or the appended content is huge

Comment: I would suggest not to use `setInterval`. Instead, based on your requirement, you can implement something like a `Publish/Subscribe` mechanism. The idea is that whenever any new data changes happen, the server should send a response to the client directly, thereby eradicating the use of `setInterval`

Comment: Why are people providing answers? There is no code, we are just guessing how to fix the problem. The example are good ones nonetheless, but not answering or adhering to the OP's problem. The first step should be that the OP post his code.

Comment: Hello All,
Thank you for commenting. I have added the code now. I am new to Stackoverflow so I hope all of you understand my question. Sorry for the bad format of question.

Comment: Can we take this off hold now that OP has provided code?

Answer (score 1):

The `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.

Below is one example code

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ setColor() }, 300);

function setColor() {
    var x = document.body;
    x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
}

function stopColor() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to call your AJAX 'X' amount of times, you could do something like this:

```
var intervalCount = 0;

var myAjax = setInterval(function(){ 
    myAjaxCall();
}, 2000);

function myAjaxCall() {
    // Some AJAX call here.
    window.console.log('AJAX Call: ' + intervalCount);
    intervalCount++;
    if(intervalCount >= 3) {
        clearInterval(myAjax);
        window.console.log('AJAX Calls Stopped');
    }        
}
```

This will set an interval to do your AJAX stuff 3 times, before then clearing the interval and stopping. This may help with performance, depending on your needs.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/89mwevda/ (open the console to see the logs).

Then again, in terms of performance, it's not very clear from your question / situation as to what's *really* causing you issues. If you could supply some demo code of your problem, it would help you get a better answer.

**Update based on the code you gave after the fact:**

I would avoid manipulating the DOM (appending things) in a loop and instead, do this in one-go, *after* building the string in the variable you have. Something like the following should work better (though untested):

```
setInterval(function() {    
    appendData(skipCount);
}, 120000);

function appendData(_popularSkipCount) {
    var cookieValue = $.cookie('type');         
    var _data = {
        "limit": defaultLimit - 1,
        "skipCount": _popularSkipCount
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/popular/" + cookieValue,
        data: _data,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {  
            $("#data-box").empty();
            if($(data).size() > 0) {

                var html = "";

                for(var i = 0; i < $(data).size() ; i++) {
                    html += "<div class='large-12 columns popular'><img class='image' src='" + $(data)[i].url + "' class='popular-img'><a href='/abc/" + $(data)[i].slug + "'><h4>" + name + "</h4></a><h5>" + city + "</h5></div>";
                }

                $(html).hide().appendTo("#data-box").fadeIn(1000);

            } else {
                appendData("0");
            }               
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown) {                             
            $("#data-box").empty();
            console.log(errorthrown);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I have to keep calling the ajax. It should never stop. Is it right to do so? I have put my code in question edit.

Comment: After seeing your code, I would say it's not really to do with your setInterval as such, but rather the DOM manipulation. Every time you update the DOM, it will affect performance. I'll try to update my answer to see how you can best optimize this part.